# import pytesseract error in google collab

Tags: python-tesseract

I'm getting ***No module named 'pytesseract'*** error in google collab with following code

## AUTOMATIC NUMBER PLATE RECOGNITION SYSTEM

import pytesseract
import imutils
import cv2

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'/content/drive/MyDrive/Automatic_Number_Plate_Recognition_System/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'

## Reading image

image = cv2.imread("/content/drive/MyDrive/Automatic_Number_Plate_Recognition_System/Cars.png", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

## Showing readed image

## cv2.imshow("Image",image)

## Resizing readed image

image = imutils.resize(image, width=500)

## Converting it to gray scale image

gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

## Edging the gray image

edged = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray_image, 11, 17, 17)

## Finding contours from edged

contours, new = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

## Copying image to image1

image1 = image.copy()

## Drawing Contours

cv2.drawContours(image1, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

## Sorting Contours

contour = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:30]

## Declaring count and initializing it to None

count = None

## Copying image to image2

image2 = image.copy()

## Drawing Contours

cv2.drawContours(image2, contour, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

```
# Declaring and initialization of count_n and index and new_image
count_n = 0
index = 21
new_image = []

# Iterating contours
for contour in contours:
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.018*perimeter, True)

    if len(approx) == 4:
        count = approx
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    new_image = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite("./" + str(index) + ".png", new_image)
    index = index + 1
    break

# Drawing Contours to new_image
cv2.drawContours(new_image, [count], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

# Showing new_image with label "Image of Number Plate Detected"
cv2.imshow("Image of Number Plate Detected", new_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Initializing img with cropImage.png
img = "./cropImage.png"

# Showing Cropped Image
cv2.imshow("Cropped Image", cv2.imread(img))

# Converting image to string
number = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng')

# Filtering the number got from converting image to string
final_number = "".join(number.split()).replace(":", "").replace("-", "").replace(";", "").replace(".", "")

# Printing number detected from image
print("Number on Number Plate : ", final_number)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install pytesseract with pip. You can use the `!` magic to run bash in a collab notebook. In the 1st cell:

```py
!pip install pytesseract
```

then in cell #2:

```py
import pytesseract 
import imutils 
import cv2
```